# C# TripleDES CBC/PKCS7/Hex not equivalent to Ruby/Python TripleDES

Tags: c#, python, ruby, encryption

I need to port a C# encrypt/decrypt class using 3DES with PKCS7 padding in HEX (with static key and IV) to Ruby or Python but seems the output is totally different.

Here is the C# snippets of the code:

```
public CryptoDES3()
{
  this.objCryptoProvider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
  this.CipherMode = CipherMode.CBC;
  this.PaddingMode = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
  this.EncodingType = CryptoDES3.EncodingTypeEnum.Hex;
}

/* ----- */

public string Encrypt(string strValue, string strKey, string strIV, CryptoDES3.EncodingTypeEnum intEncodingType)
{
  string str = "";
  if (strValue.Length > 0)
  {
    this.objCryptoProvider.Mode = this.CipherMode;
    this.objCryptoProvider.Padding = this.PaddingMode;
    byte[] bytes1 = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(CryptoDES3.HexDecode(strKey));
    byte[] bytes2 = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(CryptoDES3.HexDecode(strIV));
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream((Stream) memoryStream, this.objCryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor(bytes1, bytes2), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter((Stream) cryptoStream);
    streamWriter.Write(strValue);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
    string strValue1 = Encoding.Default.GetString(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, checked ((int) memoryStream.Length));
    switch (intEncodingType)
    {
      case CryptoDES3.EncodingTypeEnum.Hex:
        str = CryptoDES3.HexEncode(strValue1);
        break;
      case CryptoDES3.EncodingTypeEnum.Base64:
        str = CryptoDES3.Base64Encode(strValue1);
        break;
      default:
        str = strValue1;
        break;
    }
  }
  return str;
}

public string Decrypt(string strValue, string strKey, string strIV, CryptoDES3.EncodingTypeEnum intEncodingType)
{
  string str = "";
  if (strValue.Length > 0)
  {
    this.objCryptoProvider.Mode = this.CipherMode;
    this.objCryptoProvider.Padding = this.PaddingMode;
    byte[] bytes1 = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(CryptoDES3.HexDecode(strKey));
    byte[] bytes2 = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(CryptoDES3.HexDecode(strIV));
    string s;
    switch (intEncodingType)
    {
      case CryptoDES3.EncodingTypeEnum.Hex:
        s = CryptoDES3.HexDecode(strValue);
        break;
      case CryptoDES3.EncodingTypeEnum.Base64:
        s = CryptoDES3.Base64Decode(strValue);
        break;
      default:
        s = strValue;
        break;
    }
    str = new StreamReader((Stream) new CryptoStream((Stream) new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s)), this.objCryptoProvider.CreateDecryptor(bytes1, bytes2), CryptoStreamMode.Read)).ReadToEnd();
  }
  return str;
}

/* ----- */

internal const string DES3_KEY = "A0498F07C46808173894BB976F9726477CC0913D87DE912A";
internal const string DES3_IV = "0A9B11D6FEE830A9";
```

Here is the Ruby code with it's output to console:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'digest'
require 'openssl'

ALG = "DES-EDE3-CBC"
KEY = "\xA0\x49\x8F\x07\xC4\x68\x08\x17\x38\x94\xBB\x97\x6F\x97\x26\x47\x7C\xC0\x91\x3D\x87\xDE\x91\x2A"
IV = "\x0A\x9B\x11\xD6\xFE\xE8\x30\xA9"

def encode(data)
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new(ALG)
  cipher.key = KEY
  cipher.iv = IV
  cipher.encrypt
  result = cipher.update(data)
  result << cipher.final
  result = result.unpack('H*')
end

def decode(data)
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new(ALG)
  cipher.key = KEY
  cipher.iv = IV
  cipher.decrypt
  data = data.pack('H*')
  result = cipher.update(data)
  result << cipher.final
end

data = "test"

encoded = encode(data)
decoded = decode(encoded)

puts "Encrypted: #{encoded[0]}"
puts "Decrypted: #{decoded}"
```

output:

```
$ ./3des.rb
Encrypted: 33fd6ee287c0f46f
Decrypted: test
```

Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pyDes

k = pyDes.triple_des('A0498F07C46808173894BB976F9726477CC0913D87DE912A'.decode('hex'), mode=pyDes.CBC, IV="0A9B11D6FEE830A9".decode('hex'), pad=None, padmode=pyDes.PAD_PKCS5)
d = k.encrypt("test")

print "Encrypted: " + d.encode('hex')

print "Decrypted: " + k.decrypt(d)
```

output:

```
$ ./3des.py
Encrypted: 33fd6ee287c0f46f
Decrypted: test
```

Same output in Python using `chilkat.CkCrypt2()`.

Does MS C# `TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider()` differ to Ruby,Python,OpenSSL?
Any idea how can I get the same results?

Comment: Where is your C# output?

Comment: Couldn't make a C# stand-alone encrypt/decrypt binary, I don't know any C#

Comment: Maybe you should perform a speed course on that, because this probably also means that you don't understand how to debug this. We're not here to help you with that really.

Comment: Who is "we"? (I'll do that, anyway)

Comment: The SO community. SO is for specific questions and answers. Some members will help with debugging of course, but generally you are supposed to at least have attempted it yourself. These kind of questions have very little value for other users of the system. By the way, I'd use `ToArray` on the `MemoryStream` rather than retrieving the underlying buffer.

Comment: I know that, I'm an old member here. If you read my question you can see I put a lot of work on it, anyway is your opinion. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: There are dozens of questions like this already on [so]. In 99.9% of cases, the solution turned out to be that the person who asked the question actually encrypted different things (e.g. a UTF-16 encoded string in one language and a UTF-8 encoded string in the other language or a string with normalized line-endings vs a string without normalized line-endings, or a string which ended with a newline vs a string without a trailing newline or whatever). Are you 100000% sure that you are encrypting the same thing in all cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it work on C# also:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace _3DES
{
    class Program
    {

        public static string Encrypt(string strValue)
        {
            const string DES3_KEY = "A0498F07C46808173894BB976F9726477CC0913D87DE912A";
            const string DES3_IV = "0A9B11D6FEE830A9";
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider objCryptoProvider;
            string str = "";
            if (strValue.Length > 0)
            {
                objCryptoProvider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
                objCryptoProvider.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                objCryptoProvider.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                byte[] bytes1 = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(HexDecode(DES3_KEY));
                byte[] bytes2 = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(HexDecode(DES3_IV));
                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream((Stream)memoryStream, objCryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor(bytes1, bytes2), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter((Stream)cryptoStream);
                streamWriter.Write(strValue);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                string strValue1 = Encoding.Default.GetString(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, checked((int)memoryStream.Length));
                str = HexEncode(strValue1);
            }
            return str;
        }

        public static string Decrypt(string strValue)
        {
            const string DES3_KEY = "A0498F07C46808173894BB976F9726477CC0913D87DE912A";
            const string DES3_IV = "0A9B11D6FEE830A9";
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider objCryptoProvider;
            string str = "";
            if (strValue.Length > 0)
            {
                objCryptoProvider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
                objCryptoProvider.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                objCryptoProvider.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                byte[] bytes1 = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(HexDecode(DES3_KEY));
                byte[] bytes2 = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(HexDecode(DES3_IV));
                string s;
                s = HexDecode(strValue);
                str = new StreamReader((Stream)new CryptoStream((Stream)new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s)), objCryptoProvider.CreateDecryptor(bytes1, bytes2), CryptoStreamMode.Read)).ReadToEnd();
            }
            return str;
        }

        public static string HexEncode(string strValue)
        {
            string str = "";
            if (strValue.Length > 0)
            {
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strValue);
                int num = 0;
                int upperBound = bytes.GetUpperBound(0);
                int index = num;
                while (index <= upperBound)
                {
                    str += Conversion.Hex(bytes[index]).PadLeft(2, '0');
                    checked { ++index; }
                }
            }
            return str;
        }

        public static string HexDecode(string strValue)
        {
            string str = "";
            if (strValue.Length > 0)
            {
                strValue = strValue.ToUpper();
                int num1 = 0;
                int num2 = checked(strValue.Length - 2);
                int startIndex = num1;
                while (startIndex <= num2)
                {
                    str += Conversions.ToString(Strings.Chr(Conversions.ToInteger("&H" + strValue.Substring(startIndex, 2))));
                    checked { startIndex += 2; }
                }
            }
            return str;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String encoded = Encrypt("test");
            Console.WriteLine(encoded);
            String plain = Decrypt(encoded);
            Console.WriteLine(plain);
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
C:\> 3DES.exe
33FD6EE287C0F46F
test
```